# Simple Conditional Probabilty problem

Tags: probability

> Consider a laboratory test to detect a particular disease. The following events are defined:
>
> - $A ~\sim$  person has the disease.
> - $B ~\sim$ test was positive for the disease.
>
> It is known that:
>
> - $\mathsf P (B\mid A) = 0.95$
> - $\mathsf P (B\mid A^\complement) = 0.004$
>
> and the proportion of people with the disease in the population is $\mathsf P(A)=0.0029$.
>
> > What is the probability that a person has in fact the disease given that the test was positive?

Comment: Use the reverse probability formula.

Comment: what do you mean by that?
Even using the Bayes' Theorem I can't solve the problem

Comment: Well, show in your question how you tried to use Bayes' Theorem to find $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$.  You'll get better help if you show what you've tried and what is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Use Bayes' theorem [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and the law of total probability [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/697535)

Comment: Thank's, I will consider it in the future. In this case, I believe 'Bayes' theorem' and 'the law of total probability' are the essential parts.